# JSX code snippet returns the correct value on one page but returns the wrong value on other pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

```
{_id === friendId || <IconButton
        onClick={() => patchFriend() } 
        sx={{ backgroundColor: primaryLight, p: "0.6rem" }}
      >
        {isFriend ? (
         <PersonRemoveOutlined sx={{ color: primaryDark }} />
        ) : (
         <PersonAddOutlined sx={{ color: primaryDark }} />
        )}
      </IconButton>}
```

The code allows users to add or remove friends in the application by clicking on a single button, and it displays a different icon depending on whether the two users are already friends. But it only works properly one on page (the homepage) but when i visit another user's profile, this code returns the wrong icon. There's quite a bit of moving parts in my code so I'll try to provide all the relevant variables and functions.

The first line of the code's logic prevents the user from seeing the add/remove friend icon on his/her own profile.

```
const isFriend = friends.find((friend) => friend._id === friendId);
const friends = useSelector((state) => state.user.friends);
const { _id } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
friendId is a key fetched from the backend
const patchFriend = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:3001/users/${_id}/${friendId}`,
      {
        method: "PATCH",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    dispatch(setFriends({ friends: data }));
  };
```

I've tried changing the first line to !== but it makes things more complicated. Also tried making useStates for this and modifying other variables in my other jsx files but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
    const friends = useSelector((state) => state.user?.friends);
    const isFriend = friends?.find((friend) => friend._id === friendId);

    const [state, setState] = useState(isFriend)

    useEffect(() => {
      setState(friends?.find((friend) => friend._id === 
               friendId);)
    }, [friends])
    

          {_id === friendId || <IconButton
            onClick={() => patchFriend() } 
            sx={{ backgroundColor: primaryLight, p: "0.6rem" }}
          >
            {state ? (
             <PersonRemoveOutlined sx={{ color: primaryDark }} />
            ) : (
             <PersonAddOutlined sx={{ color: primaryDark }} />
            )}
          </IconButton>}
```